# using 2 nested forms but the inner form is not showing in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I'm using two forms like that, one for choosing a category so the book related to this category will show below. One modal form inside each book to borrow a book from the library, but my problem is, modal form inside can open but can't act. I don't know why. Anybody can help me. The demo image is below

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "BorrowBook", FormMethod.Post, new { name = "demoForm" }))
        {
            @Html.DropDownList("id_category", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.listTest, "-- Tất Cả Thể Loại --",
                 new { onchange = "SelectedIndexChanged()" })

            <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: wrap;">
                @foreach (var item in ViewBag.list)
                {

                    var itemName = "#exampleModalss" + item.id_book;
                    var itemName1 = "exampleModalss" + item.id_book;
                    <div class="movies-box" style="height: 430px;width: 250px; display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center; flex-direction: column; box-shadow: 2px 2px 30px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%); margin: 20px; border-radius: 5px; overflow: hidden; border-top: 3px solid #292929;">
                        <!--img------------>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="movies-img">

                                <img src="/Content/assets/img/@item.image" style=" width: 250px; height: 300px; object-fit: cover;" />
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <h3 style="font-weight:bold">@item.name</h3>
                        <p>Số lượng còn lại: @item.quantity</p>
                        @if (item.quantity != 0)
                        {
                            <div style="margin-bottom:20px" class="button--movie">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="@itemName">Thuê sách</button>
                            </div>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <div style="margin-bottom:20px" class="button--movie">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-toggle="modal" value="Disabled">Hết sách</button>
                            </div>
                        }
                    </div>
                        <div class="modal fade" id="@itemName1" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
                                @*<form action="/BorrowBook/Add" method="post">*@
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <form action="/BorrowBook/Add" method="post">
                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">@item.name</h5>
                                                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                                            </div>
                                            <div id="resultss" class="modal-body">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-4">
                                                        <div class="movies-img">

                                                            <img src="/Content/assets/img/@item.image" style=" width: 300px; height: 400px; object-fit: cover;" />
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-4">
                                                        <h5>Thông tin sách</h5>
                                                        <div class="">
                                                            <label for="category-film" class="col-form-label" style="font-weight:bold;width : 140px">Tên sách</label>
                                                            : @item.name
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="">
                                                            <label for="category-film" class="col-form-label" style="font-weight:bold;width : 140px">Tác giả</label>
                                                            : @item.author
                                                        </div>


                                                        @foreach (var item1 in ViewBag.listP)
                                                        {
                                                            if (item1.id_publisher == item.id_publisher)
                                                            {
                                                                <div class="">
                                                                    <label for="category-film" class="col-form-label" style="font-weight:bold;width : 140px">Tên nhà xuất bản</label>
                                                                    : @item1.name
                                                                </div>
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                        <div class="">
                                                            <label for="category-film" class="col-form-label" style="font-weight:bold;width : 140px">Năm xuất bản</label>
                                                            : @item.year_publish
                                                        </div>
                                                        @foreach (var item2 in ViewBag.listC)
                                                        {
                                                            if (item2.id_category == item.id_category)
                                                            {
                                                                <div class="">
                                                                    <label for="category-film" class="col-form-label" style="font-weight:bold;width : 140px">Tên thể loại</label>
                                                                    : @item2.name
                                                                </div>
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                        <div class="">
                                                            <label for="category-film" class="col-form-label" style="font-weight:bold;width : 140px">Price</label>
                                                            : @item.price VND
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="">
                                                            <label for="category-film" class="col-form-label" style="font-weight:bold;width : 140px">Mô tả:</label>
                                                            <br> @item.description
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-4">
                                                        <h5>Thông tin sinh viên</h5>
                                                        <div class="">
                                                            <label for="category-film" class="col-form-label" style="font-weight:bold;width : 140px">Tên sinh viên:</label>
                                                            : @userInfomatiom.fullname
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="">
                                                            <label for="category-film" class="col-form-label" style="font-weight:bold;width : 140px">Địa chỉ:</label>
                                                            : @userInfomatiom.address
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="">
                                                            <label for="category-film" class="col-form-label" style="font-weight:bold;width : 140px">Số điện thoại:</label>
                                                            : @userInfomatiom.phone
                                                        </div>
                                                        <label for="category-film" class="col-form-label">Ngày thuê :</label>
                                                        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="tenphim" name="start_time" tabindex="1" min="@dtnoww" required>
                                                        <label for="category-film" class="col-form-label">Ngày trả :</label>
                                                        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="end_time" tabindex="1" value="" min="@dtnoww" required>
                                                        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="idUser" tabindex="1" value="@userInfomatiom.id_user" hidden>
                                                        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="idBook" tabindex="1" value="@item.id_book" hidden>

                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                                <button style="width:100px" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Thuê</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                @*</form>*@
                            </div>
                        </div>
                }

            </div>

        }
```

Script to change category

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SelectedIndexChanged() {
        document.demoForm.submit();
    }
</script>
```

[image: Image list book by category]

When I click on each book, it can show a modal like that, but when I click on submit button, it can not respond.
[image: Modal but cannot submit button]

When I check the element, I can't see from inside (form modal)

I need help. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You cannot nest `<form>` elements in an HTML document. You need to move your modal dialog and its associated `<form>` outside of your `@using (Html.BeginForm(...)) { ... }` block.